# "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error inserting Dates into Date/Time Field in Access database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, datetime-format

I am using the Calendar extender to extend a textbox in ASP.NET inside of Visual Studio 2010. I am trying to insert the date of an event into the database along with other bits of information. I am receiving the "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error when trying to insert into the database.

I tried using DateTime.ParseExact to convert the string date to Access Date/Time but still no luck.

Here is my code behind:

> ```
> Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
>
>     Dim oleDbConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BookMeetConnString").ConnectionString)
>     Dim SqlString As String = "Insert into Events(EventTitle,EventDescription,EventDate,EventCategory) Values (@f1,@f2,@f3,@f4)"
>     Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SqlString, oleDbConn)
>
>     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", tb_eventtitle.Text)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f2", tb_eventdescription.Text)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f3", DateTime.ParseExact(tb_eventdate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy",
>     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f4", dd_eventcategory.SelectedValue)
>     oleDbConn.Open()
>     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
>     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep("2000")
>     Response.Redirect("~/calendar.aspx")
> End Sub
> ```

Here is my ASP.NET code (notice that I am also formatting the date inserted into the textbox by the CalendarExtender as "dd/MM/yyyy"):

> ```
>  <asp:TextBox ID="tb_eventdate" runat="server" ToolTip="Enter a
>  date"></asp:TextBox>
>                 <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="tb_eventdate_CalendarExtender"  Format="dd/MM/yyyy" runat="server"
>
>                     TargetControlID="tb_eventdate">
>                 </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
> ```

The field in my Access database is of type "Date/Time".

I don't know why I am having this problem as I have managed to retrieve dates from the database in another function and converted them ToString:

> ```
>     Function GetEventListing(selectedDay As DateTime) As DataTable
>     '--read event listing for the given day from an Access query
>     Dim con As OleDbConnection = GetConnection()
>     Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
>     cmd.Connection = con
>     cmd.CommandText = String.Format("Select * from EventInfo Where EventDate >= #{0}# And EventDate < #{1}#", _
>                                     selectedDay.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), _
>                                     selectedDay.AddDays(1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
>     Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
>     Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
>     da.Fill(ds)
>     con.Close()
>
>     Return ds.Tables(0)
> End Function
> ```

What could be the cause of the error I am receiving?

Comment: access database takes "-" as separator I think.. Not sure though.

Comment: Check your Region settings for the proper Date format

Comment: @George And where do I find my Region settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's not the date that's messing you up. I thought perhaps you were getting the error because you were adding a `DateTime` value as a parameter (instead of a date converted to a string formatted as `yyyy-mm-dd` or `m/d/yyyy`), but I tried the following in C# and it worked fine...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Database1.accdb;");
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Events (EventName, EventDate) VALUES (?, ?)", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", "TestEvent");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", (new DateTime(2013,3,21)));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
}
```

...so if your DateTime parsing is returning a valid DateTime value then it looks like your query *should* work.

If it really is the execution of the SQL statement that is failing, the only other likely suspect is the `dd_eventcategory.SelectedValue`. Perhaps that needs to be `.ToString()`'d...?

Comment: I just implemented your code above into the Button Click handler and it worked! I think you must be right! Thank you very much!